# как сделать чтобы звук не стакался?

Tags: unity3d

я делаю скрипт камеры, который по условию включает звук, но я столкнулся с такой проблемой что когда условие активно выполняется(условие такое что оно выполняется не раз и не два) то звуковое сопровождение стакается, тоесть что я имею ввиду под словом стакается, вопроизводится очень много звуков, так ище и звук пищания, вообще не приятно, я подумал что смогу исправить это недорозумение созданием переменной, но это тоже не помогло потому-что по факту переменная включена, и значит звук вопроизводится вечно и повторяется, и дорогие судари, как я мог бы и могу исправить сие недорозумение в виде стакающегося звука, тоесть сделать так чтобы звук воспроизводился только один раз в отведенное время? буду признателен за ваши ответы, ведь любая помощь это помощь, ответ может лежать прямо у меня под носом, но я его не замечаю, принимаю и такое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хочешь, чтобы звук воспроизводился раз в определëнное время, то используй корутины
https://youtu.be/OzCI06es5QQ

Если только один раз, то делай в Start

Comment: а в старт можно прописать if?

Comment: Да, как и в любой метод

Comment: в старт нельзя прописать иф, юнити выделяет ошибку